# Where is this image of Vader from?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, image-identification

[image]

I see this image everywhere but can’t figure out where it is.

Comment: It appears on [Vader's Databank page on starwars.com](https://www.starwars.com/databank/darth-vader).

Comment: @Null - That sounds like an answer to me

Comment: @Valorum The only problem is [the oldest version of the image found by tineye](https://tineye.com/search/10a476d44fba946582271b0f3749d82daa3fca87?sort=crawl_date&order=asc&page=1) is from twitter.

Comment: @Null - Google Images dates it to 2016

Comment: @Valorum The only 2016 result I found from Google Images led to an unrelated YouTube video—if that's the one you found, the result was probably scraped from video recommendation thumbnails.

Comment: @MiloP - Aye. Google Images has been going steadily downhill in usefulness for years

Answer (score 28):

This is a [production still](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_still) from the [2022 *Obi-Wan Kenobi* series](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi_(television_series)):

[image: Image of Darth Vader embedded within the starwars.com website]

<sub>Source: https://www.starwars.com/obi-wan-kenobi-stills-gallery</sub>

It depicts Vader on the [unidentified moon](https://www.starwars.com/databank/barren-moon) from the sixth and final episode.

Comment: _That’s no moo—_ wait, sorry, yes it it.

Comment: _That's no moo..._ -- 

Comment: Gotta milk this for all it's worth, no matter how cheesy the subject matter.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFjlW_OkMl8 tl;dr https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62a9FDAJj2Y